# msi file built in Jenkins sometimes gets detected as trojan as sometimes not

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, windows-installer, trojan

I have a problem with a C# application built inside the Jenkins Build Environment of my company: the application sometimes is detected as trojan and sometimes not. 
After I build this C# application, I always scan it with VirusTotal. Sometimes the application gets detected as Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.C!ml or as Program:Win32/Wacapew.C!ml, and sometimes not. 
What is really strange for me, is the fact that the two same msi files, built from the exactly same source code, without any change between one build and the next one, one time is detected as trojan and the next time not. 
I'm 100% sure that the detection is a false positive. But why there's this different behaviour? The problem is on the Jenkins side or on the scan side?

Comment: The state of the scan services will change over time depending on how many false positives have been reported back to them. Even if you use the same msi it can today be ok and tomorrow not.

Comment: This is the same MSI being detected and not detected on different days? Or just two identical MSI files built from the same source?

Comment: The msi files are different but have been built from the same source code. Then these have been tested in different days.
Anyway, I had the same suspect of @AloisKraus: only Windows detect the msi file as virus, so it must be related to some change in this Windows scan service.